# How to extract information from commit log in cassandra?

Tags: database, encoding, cassandra, zip, compression

I have a commit log file extracted from cassandra (CommitLog-7-1593076543244.log), but it seems the file is compressed and like a binary file. And when I open it in vscode with 'utf-8' encoding, it seems like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7dNN.png).
So how can I recover/decompress the file and extract useful information from the commit log?
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Cassandra uses the `commit log` only to restore the `Memtable` on a restart if the server previously had crashed and those records were not flushed to `SStable`.
- It is internal structure and they should be free to change the structure between versions as long as the Kafka code is backward compatible and able to restore  they can restore the `Memtable` on a server restart after a crash.
- By restarting the server (if it had crashed), that information will be restored to `Memtable` and the information will be available to you via the normal channel of `CQL` query.
- So what information you need from commit long, what is your case and why you can't achieve it via the path I have described.

Note:

May be you can write a tool easily to read a log segment by inspecting `CommitLog.recover()` method and extracting relevant code into a program.

- [CommitLog.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLog.java)
- [CommitLogReader.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogReader.java)
- [CommitLogReadHandler.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogReadHandler.java)

Comment: The way you mentioned is ok however the case is that I want to study what is restored in commit log and extract some commands for further study. Therefore when I want to do further experiment, it is better to extract information directly from the commit log file, rather than restart the server and run the code again. So the question is back to 
decode or parse the commit log file. Thanks for your help.